# Best framework for a programming beginner to make iphone games

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I've started to develop iphone games in a program called stencylworks. It is very glitchy and I'm tired of being limited by a game engine and think it would be a useful skill to learn how to program so I thought I would try and learn a framework (cocos 2d, sparrow) to make iphone games instead of using an engine. I have been using game engines since I was ten but whenever I try and teach myself a programming language it never goes well. I have almost no programming experience whatsoever and it seems that most frameworks assume you have knowledge of another language. I'm willing to learn another language first if it will make everything a lot easier but I don't really want to. I have a lot of learning resources (local library, itunesu) so if there's any books to make learning easy I can get those too.

Comment: While we can't provide an objective answer to this, I can tell you that you will most likely want to become familiar with Objective-C and the Cocoa Touch frameworks if you wish to get far along in iOS game design. While you can use game engines to abstract some of this away from you, you really should understand the underlying platform first. Also, which engine you choose (or which API to use) will depend on if you wish to develop purely 2-D games or 3-D ones.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to learn programming for a new platform you'll sometimes have to learn a new language. For native iOS development there is no way around Objective-C, so you'll have to make friends with it. Luckily it isn't hard to learn (raw C with raw C frameworks is harder). But learning a new language isn't that big a problem (from my own experience I can tell you it gets easier with each new language as the concepts keep repeating). Learning a new *framework* is what eats up the biggest amount of work and time.

There are a few books out there that discuss iPhone game development. You want to grab one that has good reviews (I can't list any since I don't any, and three months from now any list I'd make now would be outdated and thus useless to future visitors). So far Cocos2D seems to be the most popular framework for game development (next to pure native development). But before you start with that I recommend you grab a beginner's iOS development book. Not as cool as game development, but with a good understanding on how iOS development is done overall you'll have an easier (and thus more fun) time making it through a game development book.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in games, I would suggest Cocos 2d and consider the following book: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/.

If you are interested in developing games in the future, you should consider learning about the programming languages behind the engines and frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

www.unity3d.com framework 
you can also use cocos3D